# Chrome Upgrade made links subsequent columns links unclickable

Tags: css, google-chrome, hyperlink, column-count

With the recent Chrome upgrade Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit) the links in our Main menu's submenu are not clickable in any column after the first one.  [dickinsonstate.edu](http://www.dickinsonstate.edu)

Removing the columns creates one giant list of links but all of them seem to work.  I tried to work with display:flex but couldn't seem to get the nice left aligned columns we have currently.

Links are still clickable in IE and FF.

[Screen capture of Broken Links in Columns 2 and 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybarZ.png)

```
.nav-main .nav-level-2>ul{
    visibility:hidden;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    right:0;
    z-index:2;
    text-align:left;
    overflow:hidden
}
.nav-main .nav-level-2>ul:before{
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px rgba(50,50,50,.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px rgba(50,50,50,.75);
    box-shadow:1px 1px 5px rgba(50,50,50,.75);
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 19px rgba(50,50,50,.4);
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 19px rgba(50,50,50,.4);
    box-shadow:1px 1px 19px rgba(50,50,50,.4);
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    top:-100px;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0
}
.nav-main .nav-level-2>ul .submenu-links{
    column-count:3;
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-count:3
}
.nav-sorted.nav-main .nav-level-2>ul{
    display:none;
    visibility:visible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. Try setting `position:relative` and a `z-index` on the parent of the columns.